# How to show Gradle build error from library if library's core dependency is missing

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I am building a multi-module android library as follows

1. `library-core`
2. `library-ui`

I want to show Android Studio Gradle build error if anyone is adding only `library-ui` dependency without  `library-core` Avoiding runtime crash.

I have already tried `compileOnly` and `runtimeOnly` options from [Dependency Configurations](https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies?agpversion=4.1#dependency_configurations)

It does not show gradle build errors.